# 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' VueJS routing

Tags: node.js, vue.js, routes, vue-router

Basically the `router.beforeEach()` method is doing something I don't understand.

I get the jist of the issue being that when my route is re-directing to /login it will do it around 960 times or so until the error occurs.

my code is like so:

Router:

```
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path:'/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: 'false'
      }
    },
    {
      path:'/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: 'false'
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: 'True'
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

the beforeEach() method

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

    console.log(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth))
    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt') == null) {
      next({
       path: '/login',
        params: { nextUrl: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    if (localStorage.getItem('jwt') != null) {
      next({
        path: '/',
        params: { nextUrl: '/' }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
})
```

I've looked through countless threads and other places and none have the same issue as me (or I'm overlooking things). Anyone got an idea on how to fix, and what is actually happening to make the error occur in this? from what I can tell I have nothing named twice or any other function/component fire off when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it. I'm a bit special in the head. For anyone with the same issue just change the routes to

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
          requiresAuth: false
        }
    },
    {
      path:'/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Could you explain some more what you did? I don't see any changes?

Comment: @dexter, yeah basically the meta data i apply in each route i set the value of requiresAuth as a string instead of a boolean. And JS returns false on ‘true’ == true.

Comment: Ah tnx, now I see it!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets this error without any obvious mistake, try deleting node_modules and running `npm install` again.
I got this error when switching git branches and the only thing that changes were the packages, so I tried the above and it got rid of the problem :)